# How can I make a silent mode for TinyMCE editor

Tags: php, tinymce, silent

I want to create TinyMCE editor on the page, but it should boot and render only after `focus on` action. How can I do that, please, can you give advice to me.

---

### Recession

Page may have include scores TinyMCE elements, and page will hang. Therefore, the field should be converted into TinyMCE as needed, initially it's just textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [first example](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_01.php) in the documentation shows how you can toggle the editor on and off in Javascript. Just attach an `onclick` handler to your `<textarea>` that turns the editor on. Here's some jQuery-based code that I haven't tested, but should work...

```
$("textarea").click(function() {
    if (!tinyMCE.get(this.id)) {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, this.id);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but it is not exactly what I need, but close. TinyMCE does not have to render on the textarea yet have not clicked on it.

Answer (score 1):

At the manufacturer's site is all there, thanks for the tip-off Dean Harding.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_12.php